# Recreate database in Play with evolution for each test in OneAppPerTest

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I am using Playframework 2.4.6 (want to update to the new version 2.5.0) with Play-Slick.

I have problems to change my unit and integrationtests.
When I want to test my controller, I need the database in default status for each test. That means evolution should run for each test.

In my tests I am using h2 InMemory Database.

I tried to set in my testApplication.conf the values:

```
play.evolutions.autoApply=true
play.evolutions.autoApplyDowns=true
evolutionplugin=enabled
applyEvolutions.default=true
applyDownEvolutions.default=true
```

with no success.

I am using the OneAppPerTest trait, because I hoped, this trait will reset the database for each test case.
No Success.

This is my setup for my test cases:

```
class MyControllerTest extends FunSuite with OneAppPerTest with OptionValues with MockitoSugar { 

  implicit override def newAppForTest(td: TestData) = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .configure(Map("ehcacheplugin" -> "disabled", "applyDownEvolutions.default" -> "true"))
    .build()
}
```

For each test I take the controller from Guice:

```
test("test 1") {
    val controller = app.injector.instanceOf[MyController]
    controller.changeDB // Change
}
```

When I call my methods on the controller, it will change the database. This change is still there in my second test case.

Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works with:

1. Enhance the Testclass with `BeforeAndAfterEach` trait
2. write a method:

> ```
> override def afterEach() {
>   lazy val databaseApi = app.injector.instanceOf[DBApi]
>   val db = databaseApi.database("default")
>   Evolutions.cleanupEvolutions(
> }
> ```